# OneNote 2010 crashes at a certain page

Tags: crash, microsoft-onenote

I run OneNote 2010 as part of Office 2010 Professional installations on two separate machines. One installation is 32-bit, the other 64-bit, the OS is 64-bit, Windows 7 & 8, respectively.

Here's the problem:
On a specific page of my notebook, the OneNote app crashes everytime I go with the cursor over a specific area of the page. It also happens when highlighting the section.

I already tried safebooting OneNote and deleting the cache - did not help. I also reset the settings to factory defaults - no solution either.

Copying the whole page just copies the error.

When viewing the same page through OneNote's web version everything is fine.

What else can I do?

Comment: Found a workaround: Went into OneNote Web App, opened the page, selected everything (Ctrl-A twice) and then copied it to a new page. The new page does not exhibit this bug/corruption. Deleted the old one. However, since similar issues have been discussed on Microsoft forums for a while now it is annoying that they apparently still have no solution/bug fix.